# How do you re-render multiple React components inside of one parent React component in one go?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, components, rendering

I want to be able to shuffle these tickets when I click a project option in the drop down. I didn't figure it would work but I tried writing three separate useState functions for each ticket type array. I know the shuffleTickets method is being called correctly, just not doing what I want. Are you able to pass in multiple parameters for a useState function?

```
import React from "react";
import { useState } from "react";
import styles from "./Tickets.module.css";
import TicketTable from "./TicketTable";
import Modal from "./Modal";

const Tickets = () => {
  const notStartedTickets = [
    { id: 1, assignee: "trevor strnad", time: "1h" },
    { id: 9, assignee: "trevor strnad", time: "1h" },
    { id: 10, assignee: "n8 feet under ", time: "1h" },
  ];
  const inProgressTickets = [
    { id: 11, assignee: "n8 feet under ", time: "1h" },
    { id: 12, assignee: "ryan knight", time: "1h" },
    { id: 15, assignee: "trevor strnad", time: "1h" },
  ];
  const completedTickets = [
    { id: 16, assignee: "n8 feet under ", time: "1h" },
    { id: 17, assignee: "ryan knight", time: "1h" },
    { id: 18, assignee: "trevor strnad", time: "1h" },
  ];

  const [shuffledNewTickets, setShuffledNewTickets] = useState(notStartedTickets);
  const [shuffledStartedTickets, setShuffledStartedTickets] = useState(inProgressTickets);
  const [shuffledDoneTickets, setShuffledDoneTickets] = useState(completedTickets);

  const shuffleTickets = () => {


    setShuffledNewTickets(notStartedTickets.sort((a, b) => Math.random() - 0.5));
    setShuffledStartedTickets(inProgressTickets.sort((a, b) => Math.random() - 0.5));
    setShuffledDoneTickets(completedTickets.sort((a, b) => Math.random() - 0.5));


  }

  return (
    <>
      <div className={styles.create}>
        <select className={styles.projects}>
          <option value="project 1" onClick={shuffleTickets}>Project 1</option>
          <option value="project 2" onClick={shuffleTickets}>Project 2</option>
          <option value="project 3" onClick={shuffleTickets}>Project 3</option>
          <option value="project 4" onClick={shuffleTickets}>Project 4</option>
        </select>
        <button onClick={toggleNewTicketModal} className={styles.button}>
          create ticket
        </button>
      </div>
      <div className={styles.tickets}>
        {editTicketModal ? 
          <Modal onToggleModal={toggleEditTicketModal} onCreateTicket={createTicket} title={'edit ticket'}/>
        : createTicketModal ? 
        <Modal onToggleModal={toggleNewTicketModal} onCreateTicket={createTicket} title={'new ticket'} />
        : null
        }
        {/* {modal && (
          <Modal onToggleModal={toggleModal} onCreateTicket={createTicket} title={title}/>
        )} */}
        <TicketTable
          color={"red"}
          header={"not started"}
          tickets={shuffledNewTickets}
          onToggleModal={toggleEditTicketModal}
        />
        <TicketTable
          color={"blue"}
          header={"in progress"}
          tickets={shuffledStartedTickets}
          onToggleModal={toggleEditTicketModal}
        />
        <TicketTable
          color={"green"}
          header={"completed"}
          tickets={shuffledDoneTickets}
          onToggleModal={toggleEditTicketModal}
        />
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Tickets;
```

Comment: Ok but I would still have 3 separate useState functions for 3 separate ticket types. Isn't this a problem? Because if I am calling 3 separate useState functions one after the other, won't only the first one get called?

Comment: No, all 3 will work separately and update as a batch in a single rerender. But if you want, you may wish to use a nested structure like `[[], [], []]` where index 0 is not started, 1 is in progress, 2 is completed. Alternately, `{notStarted: [], inProgress: [], completed: []}`. These structures would reduce repetition since you can loop over them to render and shuffle and store in a single `useState`. Another option is one array with objects that designate which type they are, but if you need to split them into 3 columns anyway, this may be a step backward.

Comment: Oh yeah, and `.slice().sort()`--you don't want to mutate anything. As a deleted answer pointed out, that's probably what you mean when you say it's "not doing what I want"--React may not detect the mutation as a change since it's the same array.